# Microsoft Teams hijacks media keys on Mac OS

Tags: macos, microsoft-teams, media-keys

I have an annoying problem that I haven't been able to find a satisfying solution to.

If I receive/make a call via Microsoft Teams, my Back/Play/Forward buttons get hijacked by Teams until I click the desired application.

Example scenario:
I'm working listening to music, if I get an incoming call I can no longer just hit the play/pause button, because of teams. So I have to manually got to the media app, and stop the music. Once I'm done with the phone call, if I try to hit play to continue my music the teams ring tone starts playing... At this point, if I manually select my media app, and hit play, my media keys are no longer hijacked by Teams...

I found a thread where individuals launch Teams app with media keys disabled, but this solution appears to be for Windows versions only.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/teams-hijacking-of-media-buttons/c8a8d998-581a-4e54-b0d8-2753be2c3f2d

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for this is to start the teams app with the options `-disable-features=HardwareMediaKeyHandling` i.e.:

```bash
/Applications/Microsoft\ Teams.app/Contents/MacOS/Teams -disable-features=HardwareMediaKeyHandling
```

One way to do this in a way that you get to start teams from spotlight is to create a apple script that you save as an app:

```
do shell script "open \"/Applications/Microsoft Teams.app\" --args -disable features=HardwareMediaKeyHandling"
```

[source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/stop-teams-from-taking-control-of-media-keys-mac/2a56ae92-7013-4032-960e-8f2bc6f36adc)

Comment: For those of us who need more explicit instructions: (1) Open "Script Editor" (2) paste the above content into the script (3) save as "Application" type, using whatever name you want to call it (3) put that "app" somewhere where Spotlight can find it